# Leitor de QR Code embutido na minha própria activity

Tags: android, qrcode

Estou precisando implementar um leitor de QR code na minha activity, ou seja, SEM REDIRECIONAR. Usar o ZXing não vai resolver meu problema.

Para ter uma idéia, veja no seu aplicativo whatsApp, na função WhatsApp Web: Há uma activity, com um texto em cima, e tal, e aí logo abaixo um quadrado, com a câmera já ativa, só esperando para voce apontar o celular para o QrCode.

É isso que eu preciso. Desenvolver um leitor QR code dentro da minha própria activity. Sem ter que chamar outra API, redirecionar, apertar um botão pra começar, nada disso.

Detalhe importante antes de qualquer pessoa responder:  Usar o ZXing NÃO VAI RESOLVER MEU PROBLEMA exceto se você tiver modificado o código de forma que eu possa utiliza-lo NA MINHA PRÓPRIA ACTIVITY, ok :)

Alguem pode me indicar por favor um tutorial ou me dar uma dica? Utilizo Android Studio.

Comment: Você já deu uma olhada nova api do google?  [Mobile Vision](https://developers.google.com/vision/), [aqui](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/bar-codes/#5) tem um exemplo de como implementar, você pode colocar um [fragment da câmera](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_camera.htm) e usar a API do google para verificar se a imagem é um QR code

Comment: Muito obrigado! Encontrei a resposta neste link: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reading-qr-codes-using-the-mobile-vision-api--cms-24680

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar o `Barcode API` do próprio Google.

Ele suporta os formatos:

- 1D barcodes: EAN-13, EAN-8, UPC-A, UPC-E, Code-39, Code-93, Code-128, ITF, Codabar.
- 2D barcodes: QR Code, Data Matrix, PDF-417, AZTEC.

Você pode encontrar um exemplo [aqui](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader).

---

**Referências**:

https://developers.google.com/vision/barcodes-overview

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei e testei a resposta neste link, e funcionou perfeitmamente com o Vision API: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reading-qr-codes-using-the-mobile-vision-api--cms-24680

Podemos encerrar este tópico.